# How to prevent `OutOfMemory` crashing caused by putting large images on an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, crash, imageview, out-of-memory

I'm putting the image that the user chooses from the gallery inside an `ImageView`.

The problem is that sometimes these pictures can be remarkably large.

ex. , `3648 X 2736`

I have a method that after checking whether the image is bigger than 2048 X 2048 ,it resizes it by changing its height, but it doesnt work. (It still crushes):

The call:

```
if(mPhoto.getHeight()>=2048||mPhoto.getWidth()>=2048){

   image.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmap(mPhoto,200));
```

And the method itself:

```
public  Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight) {

        final float densityMultiplier = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
        int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

        photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

        return photo;
        }
```

I dont even think the method runs... as soon as the image is fetched from the file, there's a `OutOfMemory` crash.

What should I do?

It crashes even when I surround the rows where I set the image with `try{}catch{}`..

**The image is not a resource from the drawable folder. it comes from the camera, the gallery, or the internet.**

I know that I might be close to the memory limit, please dont answer the obvious. The question is how can I solve it.

Some large images DO work on some devices (new devices with lots of memory)

For Ex. The same image works on galaxy s4 but makes galaxy s1 crash.

I couldn't find any solution to this...

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: You can go the android developer site and check this [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Android developers provide sample project on how to load large bitmaps.

Comment: Check whether this link helps http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html .Also see the explanation in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMRnGDR6Cu0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should recycle the old instance of photo. Change

```
 photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);
```

with

```
  Bitmap toReturn = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true); 
  photo.recycle();

  return toReturn;
```

Also you should take a look the [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize).

Answer (score 1):

Explore the [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) methods with the [BitmapFactory.Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) parameter, this will help you scale the image properly and efficiently avoiding out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Right, `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` creates for you new instance and sure eats a lot of memory. You can try to use `photo.recycle()` to destroy old instance but sometimes even that doesn't help if you talk about "big" images.